# JFET self biasing

Tags: jfet

[image]

I'm learning JFET self biasing. what I've understood so far is the resistor R_s is used to create a bias voltage as shown. since no gate current flows that means no current in R_G so the potential of the gate is Zero because it is like connecting the gate with the zero potential (ground), then what is the purpose of the resistor R_G? they could have directly shorted the gate with ground, why this extra resistor?

Comment: Why do you say no current in \$R_G\$?

Comment: @Hearth JFET is a voltage controlled device so is there any current in gate? I am not sure, I am learning

Comment: See the answer below. There's no (significant, DC) current into the gate, but there *is* still current in that resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be current in that resistor, and there also will be no (DC) current into the gate. Here, take a look:

[image]

Comment: great! this is what I was thinking, but i was not sure. thank you.

Comment: so the resistor's purpose is to vary the voltage drop in accordance with signal so that different GS voltage produces, right?

Comment: @Sayan Not *exactly*; if the signal is a voltage it doesn't need that resistor. But the resistor keeps the gate pulled to 0 volts if the signal is disconnected; leaving a FET's gate floating is poor form.

Comment: yes now understood.